# how to access the registered ActiveX control from the LAN network computer?

Tags: c#, apache, activex, webserver

I have developed the ActiveX control & register with Common CLSID number .
using the CLSID number accessing the active X control on the internet explorer (as web page).using following .html file

```
html
   body
      OBJECT id="GlobasysActiveX"  width="1000" height="480" runat="server" classid="CLSID:E86A9038-368D-4e8f-B389-FDEF38935B2F"
    /  OBJECT
   /body
/html
```

& install the Apache web server for win32 & save this page into the Apache default pages directory (
 Collapse | Copy Code
C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs
)
then access the web page from the LAN network computer (//192.168.0.159/web.html)ip address & web page name. simple web page access from the network but the ActiveX control object tab can no access .it display the picture box & cross sign .
how to access the registered ActiveX control from the LAN network computer?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You must install the ActiveX control in question on each client computer. If you want the page itself to offer it as a download, add a CODEBASE attribute to your object tag that contains the URL of the .DLL or OCX file that the browser should download. For download and install to work inside the browser, you must digitally sign the file: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx

Comment: i have written the codebase into the object tag it asked for download the ActiveX control & i have stored the dll file into the apache htdocs folder it start downloading but it display the message box as Error “Windows has blocked this software because it cannot verify the publisher” any solution